# How do I Read a text File with below structure and assign in to Object class

Tags: java, file, yaml

The text File to read is provided below -

1. context:dev
2. region:asia
3. lob:all
4. projects: (This is a list of project)
5. name:hub
6. topics: (List of Topic inside projects)
7. dataType:0
8. name:cdc
9. plan:dev-rack
10. dataType:0.dlq
11. name:cdc
12. plan:rack
13. dataType:0
14. name:raw
15. plan:dev
16. schemas:
17. value.schema.file:-data-hub.raw.0-value-v1.json
18. value.format:JSON
19. dataType:Produce.dlq
20. name:raw
21. plan:ack
22. schemas:
23. value.schema.file:hub.raw.0-value-v1.json
24. value.format:JSON
25. dataType:0
26. name:dom
27. plan:dev
28. schemas:
29. value.schema.file:dom.0-value-v1.json
30. value.format:JSON
31. dataType:Produce.dlq
32. name:dom
33. plan:de
34. schemas:
35. value.schema.file:0-value-v1.json
36. value.format:JSON

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Parameter {
    private String context;
    private String region;
    private String lob;
    private List<Project> Project;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Project {
    private String name;
    private List<Topic> topics;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Topic {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private String plan;
    private Schemas schemas;

    public boolean checkDlq(String dataType) {
        dataType = getDataType();
        if (dataType.contains("dlq")) {
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Schemas {
    private Value value;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Value {
    private Schema schema;
    private String format;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Schema {
    private String file;
}
```

Details : So I have to read above file line by line and add all the  details in Parameters class and print it.

Example:  context:dev so i have to read the dev part and put it inside parameter.setContext("dev"); but without hard coding it.

I Tried reading it but i was not able to find out how do we apply nested hashMap. As there is a list of project and inside there is list of Topics.

Edit: Purpose of reading this file is that , after reading i have to convert it in Yaml format file.

Edit: Below is the example i.e. I have to convert the text file into Yaml. The example is of yaml file (I have to convert my plain text file into this).

```
context: "dev"
region: "asia"
lob: "all"
projects:
  - name: "hub"
    topics:
    - dataType: "0"
      name: "cdc"
      plan: "devrack"
    - dataType: "0.dlq"
      name: "cdc"
      plan: "dev-bronze-rack"  
    - dataType: "0"
      name: "raw"
      plan: "rack"
      schemas:
        value.schema.file: "hub.raw.0-value-v1.json"
        value.format: "JSON" 
    - dataType: "Produce.dlq"
      name: "raw"
      plan: "devrack"
      schemas:
        value.schema.file: "raw.0-value-v1.json"
        value.format: "JSON"
    - dataType: "0"
      name: "dom"
      plan: "rack"
      schemas:
        value.schema.file: "0-value-v1.json"
        value.format: "JSON"
    - dataType: "0.dlq"
      name: "dom"
      plan: "dev"
      schemas:
        value.schema.file: "v1.json"
        value.format: "JSON"
```

Edit : I Came up with one solution But there is one Problem i.e -> if there is only one project list(starting from name parameter) line 5, the soluition is working fine, but if i put next list of project (starting with -name itself) after line 36. It is not creating next list of project and adding all the details inside list of topics.  **Below is the solution code**

```
public class YamlProcessor {

    public void addToObject() throws IOException {

        Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:/Users/zk72/Desktop/schema.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        List<Topic> addTopic = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Project> addProject = new ArrayList<>();
        //Single Variable
        Map<String, String> singleVariable = new HashMap<>();
        //For Project list - eg-> project1 , list of project
        Map<String, Map<String,String>> projects = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Map<String,Map<String,String>>> ps = new HashMap<>();
        //For Topics List - eg-> topic1, list of project
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> topics = new HashMap<>();

        while (line != null) {
            String s[] = line.split(":");
            switch (s[0]) {
                case Constants.CONTEXT:
                    singleVariable.put(s[0],s[1]);
                    break;

                case Constants.REGION:
                    singleVariable.put(s[0],s[1]);
                    break;

                case Constants.LOB:
                    singleVariable.put(s[0],s[1]);
                    break;

                case Constants.PROJECTS:
                    Map<String, String> project = new HashMap<>();
                    Map<String, String> topic = new HashMap<>();
                    int projectCount = 1;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String ss[] = line.split(":");
                        if (ss[0].equals(Constants.NAME)) {
                            if (!project.isEmpty() && project != null) {
                                projects.put("project"+projectCount, project);
                                projectCount++;
                                project = new HashMap<>();
                                project.put(ss[0],ss[1]);
                            }else {
                                project.put(ss[0],ss[1]);
                            }
                        }else if (ss[0].equals(Constants.TOPICS)) {
                            int topicCount = 1;
                            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                                String str[] = line.split(":");
                                if (str[0].equals(Constants.DATA_TYPE) && !str[0].equals(Constants.NAME)) {
                                    if(!topic.isEmpty() && topic !=null){
                                        topics.put("topic"+topicCount, topic);
                                        topicCount++;
                                        topic = new HashMap<>();
                                        topic.put(str[0],str[1]);
                                    } else {
                                        topic.put(str[0],str[1]);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if(str.length > 1)
                                        topic.put(str[0],str[1]);
                                }

                            }
                            topicCount++;
                            topics.put("topic"+topicCount, topic);
                        }
                    }
                    projectCount++;
                    projects.put("project"+projectCount, project);
            }
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        parameter.setContext(singleVariable.get(Constants.CONTEXT));
        parameter.setRegion(singleVariable.get(Constants.REGION));
        parameter.setLob(singleVariable.get(Constants.LOB));

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String,String>> entry: topics.entrySet()) {
            Topic topic = new Topic();
            topic.setDataType(entry.getValue().get(Constants.DATA_TYPE));
            topic.setName(entry.getValue().get(Constants.NAME));
            topic.setPlan(entry.getValue().get(Constants.PLAN));

            Schemas schemas = new Schemas();
            Value value = new Value();
            Schema schema = new Schema();

            schema.setFile(entry.getValue().get(Constants.VALUE_SCHEMA_FILE));
            value.setSchema(schema);
            value.setFormat(entry.getValue().get(Constants.VALUE_FORMAT));
            schemas.setValue(value);

            topic.setSchemas(schemas);
            addTopic.add(topic);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry: projects.entrySet()) {
            Project project = new Project();
            project.setName(entry.getValue().get(Constants.NAME));
            project.setTopics(addTopic);
            addProject.add(project);
        }

        parameter.setProjects(addProject);

        System.out.println(parameter.toString());

        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        options.setIndent(2);
        options.setPrettyFlow(true);
        options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("./src/main/resources/topology3.yml"));
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
        yaml.dump(parameter, writer);
        bufferedReader.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        YamlProcessor processor = new YamlProcessor();
        processor.addToObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file that you posted is correct? Those lines are "suspicious" to me: 
#4, #6, #(16/17), #(22/23), #(28/29) and #(34/35). At first sight it looked like a properties file to me but then I saw that there are repeating keys, some lines don't seem to have a value while others have no key. And as you are mentioning yaml: does the file have any indenting? You will have to format it as "code" in your question (and so without line numbers) to get indenting right.

Comment: I have updated the Post and provided example of yaml file, that is to be produced. And as of #4 - it is List of project with parameters ( name , List of Topics). I have provded all classes for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In yaml you should have nested parameters also. So you should add child parameters to your Parameter class like:

```
public class Parameter {
    private String context;
    private String region;
    private String lob;
    private List<Project> topics;
    private Set<Parameter> subParameters;

}
```

So in line 35,36. They are child of value parameter.

And how Projects and Topics related to each other? Can you give any example for it

Comment: As I have listed all the classes , you can see that in Topic class there is Schemas parameter, so   Topic -> Schemas -> Value(have two parameter i.e. String format and Schema class) -> And inside Schema -> String file.   And Relation of project and topic is -> Projects is a parent list and Topics is list inside Project. (I hope that i Have answered your question}

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert the input file to yaml, you don't need to completely deserialize it into objects first.

You only need to add various prefixes / indenting depending on the key. To distinguish the project from the topic, I simply relied on the order of keys: if `name` comes in the line following `dataType` I let it be an element of  topic, otherwise it's an element of project.

```java
public static void convertToYaml(Reader input, Writer output) throws IOException {
  var reader = new BufferedReader(input);
  var line = reader.readLine();
  var lastLineDataType = false;

  while(null != line) {
    var pos = line.indexOf(':');
    var key = (pos >= 0 ? line.substring(0, pos) : line).trim();
    var value = (pos >= 0) && (pos < line.length()) ? line.substring(pos + 1) : "";

    var prefix = switch(key) {
      case "name" -> lastLineDataType ? "      " : "  - ";
      case "topics" -> "    ";
      case "dataType" -> "    - ";
      case "plan", "schemas" -> "      ";
      case "value.schema.file", "value.format" -> "        ";
      default -> "";
    };

    lastLineDataType = "dataType".equals(key);

    if (!key.isEmpty()) {
      output.write(prefix + key + ": ");
      output.write(value.isBlank() ? "" : '"' + value.trim() + '"');
    }
    output.write("\n");
    line = reader.readLine();
  }
}
```

No validation of the input happens, so the "sh*t in -> sh*t out" principle fully applies ;-)

This code makes use of Java 17 features, so you might have to change the `switch` a bit to work with older Java versions.